# Magento 1.8 Newsletter subscriber name does not show

Tags: magento-1.8, newsletter

can anybody tell why my `{{var subscriber.CustomerFirstname}}` does not work in my newsletter? If I try `{{var subscriber.CustomerLastname}}` does also not show any name in the newsletter. Am I doing something wrong here?

Thanks for any hint.

Answer (score 1):

Try that code, but it should work only for customers, the name of the guests is unknown.

```
{{htmlescape var=$customer.name}}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work either.

Comment: This is what worked at the end {{var subscriber.customer_firstname}}